# Joins in mongodb documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, left-join

I am creating an application related to e-books for both authors and readers. Schema is written in mongodb with 2 collections USERS and AUTHORS. USRES store the data of every person signed up in the application. In USERS i have email document. A user can also register as an author in the application. (What I want to do is when a User register as an AUTHOR the email from USER document automatically become the email document in AUTHOR collection. And every AUTHOR have specific email which they used for registration. How to do that in mongodb???)

Comment: Hello, try using the pre hook that mongoose provides https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html . This allows you to set the pre-hook and check if there is an flag called `AUTHOR`on the users schema

Answer (score 0):

I can sugest u a simple option

Creating 2 separate collection for user and author is a bad choice. At the end both uses same application

Basically just add one more field is `user`
Collection as `isAuthor`

Users schema

```
"_id": id,
email: {type: String},
isAuthor: {type: Boolean} true/false
```

After this u don't need to copy emails and stuff from 2 different Collections